# Applications run inside of Netbeans scaling issue

Tags: java, netbeans

Related to, but different from, [NetBeans IDE scaling on Windows 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23651486/netbeans-ide-scaling-on-windows-8)

I've already updated the NetBeans.conf file (as above), so NetBeans is working fine.  I also have updated my JNLP files, so end users get the proper scaling of the deployed application.  However, there's one remaining case that is unsolved.  Running my application inside NetBeans exhibits the original scaling issue despite the config change.  Doing the obvious of adding the -Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=false parameter to the VM Options in the Run section of Project Properties appears to have no effect.  I know other options work fine there, because I depend on a couple others.

How can I get applications run from inside NetBeans to respect the -Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=false scaling option?

Comment: this comment might be like irrelevant , but oracle is not maintaining NetBeans like it used to be ,   So try IntelliJ IDEA .. Best IDE ..even googles AndroidStudio is based on IntelliJ IDEA

Comment: NetBeans is currently moving from Oracle to Apache and development seems to have been speeding up again lately too.  8.2 just came out with some major work done.  I like IntelliJ too, but I'm not going to migrate all my NetBeans projects over at this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the application in NetBeans.  Open the task manager and find that App.  Right click on it and select "properties".  Go to the "Compatibility" tab and check the "Override high DPI scaling behavior.  Scaling performed by:" and set the drop down to "System".