# zoom netbeans editor (NOT TEXT)

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8

I have just installed netbeans on a new temporary laptop, the screen resolution is a lot higher than my normal 1080p screen, and the netbeans GUI it self, is very difficult to use because the GUI elements are extremly small. My main problem is very difficult to google as I get thousands of resulst on "how to zoom text" or "how to zoom code"..... I don't need to zoom text, I need to zoom the GUI/editor it self (if possible) anyone know how to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved it for me.

[NetBeans IDE scaling on Windows 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23651486/netbeans-ide-scaling-on-windows-8?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

> - Open C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0\etc\netbeans.conf
> - Change -J-Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=true to -J-Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=false

Answer (score 0):

You can click (`Ctrl` + `PgUp`) or (`Ctrl` + `PgDn`) to zoom