# swing output is to small in netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

look at the image and you will understand what my problem [image]

that's happened in this computer which is 4k UHD

this problem was under netbeans itself but i fix it using [netbeans-ide-scaling-on-windows-8-10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23651486/netbeans-ide-scaling-on-windows-8-10)

when i tried to test it under  `swing` this problem appear again.

`setSize` and `setFont(new Font(MAX_FONT_SIZE))` are not what i'm looking for.

my working environment is:

- windows 10 home
- netbeans v8.0.2

Comment: You fix it the same way: https://superuser.com/questions/988379/how-do-i-run-java-apps-upscaled-on-a-high-dpi-display

Comment: @markspace thank you but  i tried to use the compatibility option unfortunately  not worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you are not preparing the dimension on jframe.
Go to the design panel and click jframe.
set the preferredSize, width, height to change the size of jframe on properties window.
I think that it will be work.