# Scene Builder preview shows all objects much larger than end result

Tags: user-interface, netbeans, fxml, scenebuilder

Here we have a preview of a window in Scene Builder behind the actual result when run with Netbeans. You can also see that my minimum sizes are set to USE_PREF_SIZE, with the values being auto-filled when I adjust the size of the window. The size difference between the windows is the first obvious difference.

[image: scene builder vs actual]

Further, you'll notice that everything inside the window is smaller as well, all buttons, tables, fonts, etc.

I'm using Netbeans 8.2, Scene Builder 11.0.0, and JDK 8 update 251. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! Hopefully this will be of some use to another aggravated user somewhere in the world.

The issue for me is that Windows was automatically scaling NetBeans. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23651486/netbeans-ide-scaling-on-windows-8-10) resource for how to stop it:

> Windows 10 does this for you now. Right click on your Netbeans shortcut (C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\NetBeans) and select Properties. Go to the Compatibility tab and then select Change High DPI Settings. From there, check the Override High DPI Scaling box and set it to System.